# Button animation only works for specific margin

Tags: html, css

I've got some strange problem. In my code the button css animation only works if the margin-top is set to be 125px (for sim-button class). I want to reduce the margin-top to 25px but then the animation doesn't works.

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRLPGR)

HTML:

```
<div class="media" style = "background-color:#000;">
                          <img class="media__image" src="https://www.offensive-security.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/security-risk-assessment-report.png">
                          <div class="media__body">
                            <h2>Penetration Report</h2>
                            <p>Get your hands on our Sample Presentation Report</p>
                            <div class="sim-button button1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#getQuoteModal">Download Report</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .media {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.media__image { display: block; }

.media__body {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3.75em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.media__body:hover { opacity: 1; }

.media__body:after,
.media__body:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 1em;
  content: '';
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
}

.media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}

.media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}

.media__body:hover:after,
.media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.media__body h2 { margin-top: 0; }

.media__body p { margin-bottom: 0em; }





.sim-button{
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 125px;
    width: 60%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.button1 a{
    color: rgba(51,51,51,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.button1:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;    
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button is being hidden underneath of your overlay:

```
z-index: 1;
```

putting the above into your sim-button class gets the effect you want. It brings your button to the foreground and is able to be hovered over to activate the animation.

here is a fiddle I made with the change added in:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wintersjmw/y0yur6jt/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, if you want the text to be selectable and the button effect to work and be clickable is to set `z-index: 1` on `.media__body`, then `z-index: -1` on the `::before/::after` pseudo elements. That will put the pseudo elements behind all of the content in `.media__body` but keep them from going behind `.media__body`

```css
.media {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.media__image {
  display: block;
}

.media__body {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3.75em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.media__body:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.media__body:after, .media__body:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 1em;
  content: '';
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}

.media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}

.media__body:hover:after, .media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.media__body h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.media__body p {
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}

.sim-button {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 60%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.button1 a {
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="media" style="background-color:#000;">
  <img class="media__image" src="https://www.offensive-security.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/security-risk-assessment-report.png">
  <div class="media__body">
    <h2>Penetration Report</h2>
    <p>Get your hands on our Sample Presentation Report</p>
    <div class="sim-button button1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#getQuoteModal">Download Report</div>
  </div>
</div>
```